# split date into weeks/date/time

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a single SQL column (RegisterDate) which include date and time together, in addition to 6 zeros: Just like this:

`2016-10-07 14:50:32.000000`

How can I split it into three columns: `Date` - `Time` - `Week`  as well as removing these zeros.

I'm using oracle SQL developer

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Week? Which one? ISO or some national specific?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ISO; just the number of the week.

Comment: I'm just using sql in oracle sql developer.

Comment: For Oracle, check out this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210

It lists all the different elements that can be used to convert dates / times including example queries. You'll need some kind of `SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE(...), ...) FROM ...` query to fill your new columns. Depending on your expected result format, you'll just need to use the corresponding elements from the linked article.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
TO_CHAR(RegisterDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS RegisterDate,
TO_CHAR(RegisterDate, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS RegisterTime,
TO_CHAR(RegisterDate, '"W"IW') AS RegisterWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT To_date(RegisterDate,'dd/mm/yyyy') RegisterDate,
 To_char(RegisterDate,'hh24:mi:ss') Registertime,
 To_Char(To_Date(RegisterDate,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'IW') Registerweek